# Continue for loop with while loop inside after exception?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to scrape a bunch of websites, that are needed to be scrolled down and clicked on a button. Each url has same structure, but has different number of click times.

My code:

```
for url in url_list:
while True:
    wd.get(url)
    last_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        #time.sleep = time for waiting
        time.sleep(3)
        new_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    next_button = wd.find_element_by_link_text('next >>')
    next_button.click()
```

However, the code finished only the first url and returned error: "NoSuchElementException". It didn't continue the loop, and sometimes if I changed url list, it stopped in the middle of the loop with error: "ElementClickInterceptedException"

My goal is to continue and finish the loop, and ignore the error.

How can I improve the code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some minimal reproducible example such as url or html?

Comment: sorry, I just updated the url_list. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and use try..except block if element found then click else break.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url_list = ['https://pantip.com/profile/2892172#topics','https://pantip.com/profile/5239396#topics','https://pantip.com/profile/349866#topics']
wd=driver=webdriver.Chrome()
for url in url_list:
    print(url)
    wd.get(url)
    while True:
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            next_button=WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a.next.numbers')))
            next_button.click()
        except:
            print("No more pages")
            break

driver.quit()
```